# How to set Initial DeskBand Width?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell, deskband

I have a deskband based on the MS sample.  It shows as an item via right click taskbar, toolbars. I find that when initially opened it's using the `DBIM_MINSIZE` instead of the `DBIM_ACTUAL` size.  Why is that?

What is the appropriate way to set the initial width (bonus, when the deskband is closed (remove checkbox from toolbar) then opened again, how do you have it use the prior width)?

TIA!

Comment: Are you aware deskbands are a legacy technology?

Comment: You may want to use thumbnail toolbars in new development in place of desk bands, which are not supported as of Windows 7. (From document of [IDeskBand interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ideskband?redirectedfrom=MSDN))

Comment: There is no replacement for the deskband in how I need to use and how everyone will want to use it.

Comment: Maybe (we don't know what you need in the first place), but that doesn't change the fact it's legacy (not supported, may not work, etc.)